# Scala: Appending to the end of an array which is a value in a HashMap

Tags: arrays, scala, hashmap, append, type-mismatch

```
var temp = 5
val map = new HashMap[String,Array[Integer]]()
if(map contains str1){
   map(str1) = map(str1) :+ temp
}else{
   map(str1) = Array(temp)
}
```

Basically if the key is not in the map, I want to set the value to a new array with the value temp and if the key is already in the map I want to append temp to the end of the existing array. temp is an Integer.

I'm getting the following error when I execute the code above:

```
helloworld.scala:21: error: type mismatch;
 found   : Array[Any]
 required: Array[Integer]
Note: Any >: Integer, but class Array is invariant in type T.
You may wish to investigate a wildcard type such as `_ >: Integer`. (SLS 3.2.10)

                        map(str1) = (map(str1) :+ temp)
                                               ^
```

I am new scala, so I'm completely lost as to why this is happening. Thanks for any help.

Comment: What is `temp`? How did you declare it?

Comment: It is an integer. i.e. var temp = 5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two problems with this code. I'm assuming you're using a mutable `HashMap` first of all, because you'd otherwise not be able to update it.

First, you're getting a compile error because you've declared a `HashMap[String, Array[Integer]]`, but you're trying to append an `Int` to the `Array[Integer]`. They are not the same thing. Therefore the compiler infers the type as `Any`, which isn't allowed because the type parameter of `Array` is invariant.

So change your declaration to `val map = new HashMap[String,Array[Int]]()`. There's isn't much of a reason to use `Integer` in scala. And if you really need to then use `val temp = new Integer(5)`, instead.

The second problem that you haven't been able to see yet from the first compiler is that this won't work:

```
map(str1) = Array(temp)
```

If the `str1` key does not exist on the `HashMap`, then calling `map(str1)` will throw an exception, so a new key cannot be assigned this way. Instead, you have to add the key-value pair to the map like this:

```
map += (str1 -> Array(temp))
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. Unrelated, but any idea why the cube of a large number would be negative in scala? i.e. 10212*10212*10212 = -194041280

Comment: @user2701040 32-bit integer overflow.